# Connecting React Login to express/SQL server backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to make just a simple login as the code snippets I have added are trying to show.

All I want to do is when user clicks the submit button the information within the login form is checked against the database and will then authenticate them if it works.

I could not get the button to to allow for the data to be sent.(The button was not always a link to a separate page but I honestly just couldn't get it working regardless).

Any advice or if you can spot anything I am overlooking would help greatly.

This is my LoginPage.js

```
import React from "react";

import "../bootstrap.min.css";
import logo from "../codestone logo.png";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import ResetPassword from "./ResetPassword";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { relative } from "path";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";

import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import "./Login.css";

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <LoginForm />

    </div>
  );
}

const LoginForm = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Logging in", values);
        setSubmitting(false);
      }, 500);
    }}
    validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
      email: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required("Required")
        .matches(/(?=.*outlook)/, "This is not a outlook email address."),

      password: Yup.string()
        .required("No password provided.")
        .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
        .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
    })}
  >
    {props => {
      const {
        values,
        touched,
        errors,
        isSubmitting,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        handleSubmit
      } = props;
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} action="auth" method="POST">
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              name="email"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              value={values.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email && (
              <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
            )}
            <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
            <input
              name="password"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
            />
            {errors.password && touched.password && (
              <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
            )}
            <button type="submit" formaction="/auth">
              <Link to="auth"> Login </Link>
            </button>
            <p>
              <Link to="/Register"> Sign Up </Link>
            </p>
            <p>
              <Link to="/reset"> Reset Password </Link>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
);

function Header() {
  return (
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <img
        className="profile-image"
        alt="icon"
        src={logo}
        width="450"
        height="80"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

This is my server.js 
(Config edited but does work)

```
const express = require("express");
const sql = require("mssql");

var express = require("express");
var session = require("express-session");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
const config = {
  user: "sas",
  password: "-------",
  server: "-----", // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  database: "-----"
};

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "login",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/login", function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/loginPage.js"));
});

app.post("/auth", function(request, response) {
  var username = request.body.username;
  var password = request.body.password;
  if (username && password) {
    config.query(
      "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",
      [username, password],
      function(error, results, fields) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
          request.session.loggedin = true;
          request.session.username = username;
          response.redirect("/home");
        } else {
          response.send("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
        }
        response.end();
      }
    );
  } else {
    response.send("Please enter Username and Password!");
    response.end();
  }
});

app.get("/home", function(request, response) {
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    response.send("Welcome back, " + request.session.username + "!");
  } else {
    response.send("Please login to view this page!");
  }
  response.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to query your API and get a reply.  From what I can see, after clicking on the button you want to send to '/auth', but it doesn't because you can't do it.

Express runs on a non-react JS sweat and you can't navigate between pages anyway.

Define the boundary between the application (reactjs) and the API server (express). To get information from express, use fetch or axios in reactjs.

Here are a couple of things to remember:

1. Do not switch to express to / home as it will do nothing.  Go to home in the reactjs app after getting a good response from the server.
2. See how to send HTTP status as a result to more easily provide information about success (401 - unauthorized) (200 - all ok)